# BASH variable interpretation when downloading genome sequences from ftp links in a script

Tags: bash, variables, ftp, bioinformatics

I've been trying to download genome sequence data using ftp links following instructions found here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/doc/ftpfaq/

I have the ftp links for my sequences in the last column of a tsv table, which I am extracting from each line in a for loop using the code below:

```
$ ftp=`head -$line_number $input_table | awk -F '\t' '{print $NF}' | tail -1 | sed 's/\"//g'`
```

The `sed` command at the end is to remove double quotes from the output, which `wget` and `rsync` were otherwise interpreting as part of the string (causing them to fail).

To download each sequence, I added the lines from the link above to the loop (exact code below):

```
$ wget --recursive --no-host-directories --cut-dirs=6 "${ftp}" -P "new_directory/"
```

I also tried downloading with https and rsync, changing the link as suggested by adding `sed 's/ftp/rsync/'` or `sed 's/ftp/https/'` into the pipeline for my `ftp` variable:

```
$ rsync -rvth --copy-links --prune-empty-dirs "${ftp}" "new_directory/"
$ wget --recursive -e robots=off --reject "index.html" --no-host-directories --cut-dirs=6 "$ftp" -P "new_directory/"
```

Within my script, these commands failed to find the right directories (see errors below).

FTP: `$ No such file ‘GCA_000048645.1_ASM4864v1\r’.`

RSYNC: `rsync: link_stat "/all/GCA/000/048/645/GCA_000048645.1_ASM4864v1\#015" (in genomes) failed: No such file or directory (2)`

However, when I tried outside of my script, feeding each link (as output by an `$ echo $ftp` line in the script) directly into the commands above worked and the downloads were succesful. The output also matches the links in the original table (example below).

```
 ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/048/665/GCA_000048665.1_ASM4866v1
```

I figure there must be a mistake in my syntax or the way BASH is reading my variables but I don't know enough about variable substitution in BASH to troubleshoot this? can anyone suggest what my problem might be?

NB: I have tried adding both double quotes and parentheses to all other variables in the script (such as the line_number and input file variables in the line above) as well as different combinations of these but to no avail. For simplicity's sake, I have not included my full script but I have checked the remainder for bugs and the issue certainly seems to be with the interpretation of the ftp variable, so I've tried to include all my code surrounding that. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The file has CRLF newlines, you need to remove the `\r` characters at the end of the line.

Comment: Your input file has DOS line endings, and the carriage return is being included in the value (hence the `\r` and `\#015` in the error messages). You need either change the input files to use Unix line endings, or remove the carriage return from the variable before using the value. See the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Just started using Windows for work after being on Mac for years. Still easing out the bumps, I guess.

Comment: NCBI have a Perl script for this opteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the carriage return characters. Replace

```
sed 's/"//g'
```

with

```
tr -d '"\r'
```